# Url.Action from UrlHelper return wrong url in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am getting an issue with `UrlHelper` in ASP.NET Core MVC. The issue is that I have a host like `https://xx.xx.xx.xx/auth` and using

```
Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = logoutId });
```

to return a url like

```
https://xx.xx.xx.xx/auth/Account/Logout?logoutId=...
```

When running on localhost, the url is returned correctly:

```
https://localhost:port/auth/Account/Logout?logoutId=...
```

But when I deploy to IIS, the url is returned as

```
https://xx.xx.xx.xx/auth/auth/Account/Logout?logoutId=...
```

the `auth` part was duplicated and I don't know why. I think it is about routing feature of ASP.NET but still have no clue for this.

Comment: We will need a [mcve].

Comment: you might have a point regarding the routing - I have struggled in the past getting this correct .. what I do is add the Area to the URL.Action - like :

@Url.Action("<method name>", "<controller>", new { area = "<area name>" })

Comment: What is the root directory deployed in IIS? You may deploy the project to the auth file in the root directory of the site.